Fantasy movie about a family sailing between various mythological locations
This is a live-action movie I watched many years ago when I was a kid, maybe sometime around 2000. (This is in the USA.) 
It involved a family of a father and two daughters travelling to the locations of various popular myths, such a the Minotaur's Labyrinth, Medusa's Island, or fairy court. 
They travelled by magic ship across a huge ocean. 
If I remember correctly, their goal was to recruit the magical creatures to their team, for some purpose. 
Despite the expectations of the viewer for these creatures to be evil, both Medusa and the Minotaur are actually very kind, just misunderstood. There were also two elves who joined up with the crew of the ship. 
The main antagonist was some kind of ugly goblin that wanted to kill the family for some reason (to prove his superiority to his brethren?). He sent a couple of monsters to stop the family, including a giant puppet sea monster. The sea monster was defeated by one of the daughters, who danced so beautifully that the monster just stared at her until it died (?). 
In the end, the goblin is beaten because the family managed to recruit a dragon, which burns down his base of operations. 

This is the exact plot of Voyage of the Unicorn from 2001 with Beau Bridges.

A professor, grieving for his dead wife, and his two daughters unwillingly journey to a parallel universe of fairy court, marauding trolls, and a prophecy that they will save this nether world. They board the Unicorn, a magic ship manned by elves. In the search for a dragon who will help them fulfill the prophecy, they encounter the Minotaur, Medusa, the Sphinx, an ogre, and a unicorn whose tears they need to reverse one of Medusa's misguided stares. The trolls also seek the dragon. Capture and slavery awaits failure, while faith precedes the miracle. The spirit of their mother is close to the girls, who must find courage and imagination, while Dad must keep his wits.

Here's the beginning:




That was remarkably fast. This does look like what I was remembering.
